# If $\,f$ and $g$ are continuous with compact support then $f*g$ (convolution ) is also continuous with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, continuity, convolution, uniform-continuity

I do not know how to find a compact that satisfies $f$ and $g$ support.
Could someone explain how find this new compact  ?

How $f$ and $g$ are continuous in a compact then are bounded in this compact. But,

Are $f$ and $g$ bounded in all real line?
Could someone starts the proofs?

Comment: Loosely speaking, if $f*g$ is non-zero at $x=a$, then there must be $d,c$ such that $b+c=a$ and $f(b),g(c)$ are both non-zero.

Answer (score 4):

**Compact support of $f*g$.** Assume that $\,f,g\in C_0(\mathbb R)$. In particular, there exists an $M>0$, such that $f,g$ are supported in a subset of $[-M,M]$.

Then for $x>2M$,
$$
(f*g)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,g(x-t)\,dt=\int_{-M}^M f(t)\,g(x-t)\,dt=0,
$$ 
since $x-t>M$, when $|t|\le M$ and $g$ vanishes for all such $x-t$. Similarly, $f*g$ vanishes for $x<-2M$.

**Continuity of $f*g$.**

Observe that
$$
(f*g)(x+h)-(f*g)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,\big(g(x+h-t)-g(x-t)\big)\,dt
$$
and hence
$$
|(f*g)(x+h)-(f*g)(x)|\le \max |f|\cdot \int_{-\infty}^\infty |g(x+h-t)-g(x-t)|\,dt
$$
Then the right hand side tends to zero, as $h$ tends to zero, due to the uniform continuity of $g$. Note that since $g$ is continuous in $[-M,M]$, then it is uniformly continuous in the same interval.

Comment: And the way this compact support idea works is that we could have several such intervals that we might have to consider but they all basically act the same way? Or there is really just one interval to consider?

Comment: One interval, or one closed ball, in higher dimensions.